# calling function in sql creating performance issue

Tags: sql, sql-server, function

I have a large table and a sql statement with a function in select statement which does return date value but it is affecting performance below is the code

```
select dbo.fnname(ID)
       , ID
       , MIN_DATE
       , MAX_DATE
       , count(*) 
from schema (nolock)
group by dbo.fnname(ID), ID, MIN_DATE, MAX_DATE, PROGRAM_NAME
order by dbo.fnname(ID) desc
```

Is there any other way to improve it.

Comment: Your syntax is SQL Server, so I changed the tag from mysql to sql-server.

Comment: Maybe also show what the function does. When a function is deterministic, SQL Server will be able to optimize it much better. If it does lookup in other tables, it may be better to actually skip the function and use a join (or other construct) directly.

Comment: Maybe instead of continuing to use a scalar function you can convert it to an inline table valued function. It would perform better and be more flexible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While technically not identical, the following should work well if the results for the function are deterministic (e.g. same result for same input), which I expect from reading the query.

```
select * 
from (
    select dbo.fnname(ID) idname, *
    from (
        select ID, MIN_DATE, MAX_DATE, count(*) cnt
        from schema (nolock)
        group by ID, MIN_DATE, MAX_DATE
    )
)
order by idname desc;
```

Here the function will only be evalauted once per grouped row.

Comment: This query does not do the same thing as the original query.  There is no indication in the query that the function is 1-1.

Comment: @GordonLinoff You are correct but I already noted that difference in my answer. For me, the indication that this simplification is probably correct is that the function is used in the `GROUP BY` - if the function was not deterministic, that would make no sense at all and produce unpredictable results anyways. Now even if the function is not 1-1 and returns the same name for multiple IDs, the query will continue to yield the same results as before because the original query used the `ID` in the `GROUP BY` as well.

Comment: @Lucero . . . deterministic is not sufficient.  It needs to be 1-1, unless you have an additional aggregation in the outer query.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Sorry, you lost me... What do you mean exactly with that additional aggregation?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using a CTE (or subquery):

```
with t as (
      select dbo.fnname(ID) as fnname_ID, t.*
      from schema
     )
select fnname_id, ID, MIN_DATE, MAX_DATE, count(*) 
from t
group by fnname_id, ID, MIN_DATE, MAX_DATE, PROGRAM_NAME
order by fnname_id desc;
```

This should reduce the number of calls to the function to only once per row.

Also, why do you have `PROGRAM_NAME` in the `GROUP BY` but not the `SELECT`?  I'm guessing it doesn't belong.

Comment: Ty for the reply..yes it doesn't belong there

Comment: Note that CTEs are not materialized, so this may or may not reduce the number of calls to the function. Seel also Connect entry on the topic: https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/218968/provide-a-hint-to-force-intermediate-materialization-of-ctes-or-derived-tables

Comment: @Lucero . . . CTEs are *not* materialized, but that shouldn't make a difference.  The reference to the function is only once, so SQL Server should not be calling the function again because the column is referenced.  I don't have SQL Server convenient right now, but this is easily tested using a volatile function such as `newid()`.